# Windows RPC vs XML-RPC

Tags: xml-rpc, rpc, distributed-computing, hpc, dce

Is there any benchmark about encoding/decoding certain common typed data in [Microsoft RPC NDR engine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh802751%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) ([DCE 1.1](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9692999399/)) in comparison with that in [XML-RPC-C/C++](http://xmlrpc-c.sourceforge.net/windows.php) in the de-facto C/C++ implementation in [XML-RPC](http://xmlrpc.scripting.com/default.html)?

Actually I have to choose between [Windows RPC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374358%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [XML-RPC-C/C++](http://xmlrpc-c.sourceforge.net/windows.php) to implement my own common object infrastructure for High Performance Computing on Windows. Any recommandation about which with regard to their performance? Thank you.

Best Regards,

Yang

Comment: DCE uses a binary protocol while XML-RPC uses XML on top of HTTP. I would expect that DCE is faster. Also it is deeply integrated into Windows and there are various tools in the SDK to support it (`midl` for example). I've used XML-RPC to connect a Python GUI to a C++ backend on Linux but the C++ XML-RPC implementation was tedious to use. Why not just use DCOM (which runs on top of DCE)? (Pardon my curiosity but what exactly HPC task are you going to achieve using distributed objects?)

Comment: @HristoIliev Hmm...DCOM should be what I'm looking for. It's not exactly about HPC task but currently an infrastructure of common object storage based on DHT that allows further implementation of channel in Hoare's CSP. I use DHT for scalable and fault-tolerant naming as well as load balancing of those objects. Microsoft has been doing the same in WCF, namely Peer Name Resolution Protocol (PRNP) in the recent .NET framework 3.5.

Comment: Correction: DCOM is not applicable here.